# Get url parameter with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get

I want to read out an url parameter using jquery and bind this one in a variable. I've seen a lot of ways to solve it but definitely no one worked for me.

http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/#filter=kataloge-database

**-> I'm using a '#' instead of a '&' or '?'!**

This is my current javascript:

```
function $_GET(param) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( location.hash, '' ).replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );

    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}

var filter = $_GET('filter');
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? You need all the `key` and `value` in an array?

Comment: My expected  output is the url parameter, in this case "kataloge-database". -> http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/#filter=kataloge-database

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do let me know if you need any change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;
var arguments = url.split('#')[1].split('=');
arguments.shift();
```

**Working Example**

```js
var url = "http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/#filter=kataloge-database";
var arguments = url.split('#')[1].split('=');
arguments.shift();
alert(arguments)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
var url = window.location.href;
var arguments = url.split('#').pop().split('=').pop();
```

**Working Example**

```js
var url = "http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/#filter=kataloge-database";
var arguments = url.split('#').pop().split('=').pop();
alert(arguments)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rino! :) Works fine!

Comment: Glad to here that `:)`

Comment: var arguments = url.split('page=')[1].split('&')[0];

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/#filter=kataloge-database

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

if(searchParams.has('#filter') // true {
 var param = searchParams.get('sent');
 console.log(param);
}
```